Performance Bottleneck in OpenMP Taskloop
I'm working on parallelizing a function in C++ using OpenMP to optimize nested loops for dynamic programming calculations. The function gpsa_taskloop aims to fill a 2D matrix S based on the values of X and Y, utilizing taskloop pragmas to distribute work across threads. However, despite setting up taskloop with specific grainsize values (256 for boundary initialization and 2048 for the main loop), the performance is still much slower than expected.
Here is a summary of the function structure:

Boundary Initialization:

The boundary cells are initialized with a gap penalty using two separate taskloops, where grainsize is set to 256.


Main Matrix Filling:

In the main loop, diagonal "waves" of the matrix are processed using taskloop to calculate maximum values based on match, delete, and insert operations. The grainsize is set to 2048 here.
Reductions are used to accumulate a visited counter across the threads.



Performance Issue: Despite using OpenMP with task-based parallelism and specifying grainsize, the code is not scaling well and performs poorly, especially in the "Main Matrix Filling" section. I suspect issues might be stemming from:

taskloop inefficiencies due to the nested loop structure or grainsize choice.
Overhead in task scheduling, especially with reductions.
Ineffective parallelization strategy for dependencies within wave-based computation in the main loop.

I'm looking for advice on improving performance, particularly with OpenMP configurations or alternative parallelization approaches to handle the dependencies in wave-based matrix filling.
unsigned long SequenceInfo::gpsa_taskloop(float** S) {
    unsigned long visited = 0;

    double start_time, end_time;
    double boundary_time = 0.0, main_time = 0.0;

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    unsigned long local_visited_row = 0;
    unsigned long local_visited_column = 0;

    // Boundary
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            #pragma omp taskloop collapse(1) reduction(+:local_visited_row) grainsize(256)
            for (unsigned int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
                S[i][0] = i * gap_penalty;
                local_visited_row++;
            }

            #pragma omp taskloop collapse(1) reduction(+:local_visited_column) grainsize(256)
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                S[0][j] = j * gap_penalty;
                local_visited_column++;
            }
        }
    }

    visited += local_visited_row + local_visited_column;


    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    std::cout << "Boundary conditions time: " << std::chrono::duration<float>(stop - start).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;

    // Main part
    auto start_main = high_resolution_clock::now();

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            for (int wave = 0; wave < rows + cols - 1; wave++) {
                #pragma omp taskloop shared(S,X,Y) reduction(+:visited) grainsize(2048)
                for (unsigned int i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
                    unsigned int j = wave - i;
                    if (j >= 1 && j < cols) {
                        float match = S[i - 1][j - 1] + (X[i - 1] == Y[j - 1] ? match_score : mismatch_score);
                        float del = S[i - 1][j] + gap_penalty;
                        float insert = S[i][j - 1] + gap_penalty;

                        float max_val = std::max({match, del, insert});
                        S[i][j] = max_val;
                        visited++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    auto stop_main = high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    std::cout << "Main conditions time: " << std::chrono::duration<float>(stop_main - start_main).count() << " seconds" << std::endl;

    return visited;
}

What I Tried:

Using #pragma omp taskloop with grainsize: I used taskloop in OpenMP with a specified grainsize (256 for boundary initialization and 2048 for the main loop) to attempt efficient parallelization. The goal was to distribute tasks across threads effectively, assuming that a higher grainsize for the main loop would reduce overhead and improve performance by creating fewer but larger tasks.

Applying reduction clauses: To correctly accumulate the count of visited cells across threads, I added reduction(+: visited) in both the boundary and main loop sections.

Attempting wave-based parallelism: For the main loop, I organized the computation in diagonal "waves" to handle dependencies while maximizing parallel execution. Each wave is processed with OpenMP tasks, which I expected to speed up execution by allowing independent tasks within the wave to execute concurrently.


What I Expected:
For a matrix of size [51481 x 53641], the sequential version takes around 12 seconds. I expected the parallelized version to perform significantly better and complete within 1-2 seconds. However, the current parallel implementation only reduces the runtime to 7-8 seconds, which is an improvement but far from the speedup I anticipated. I’m looking for ways to optimize further, aiming to bring the execution time down closer to 1-2 seconds.

Use steady_clock for timing purposes, not high_resolution_clock. Take it from the library author.

Some critical details are missing to understand the timings and bottlenecks. First, what is the exact target CPU (i.e. CPU reference)? What is are the DRAM configuration? What is the target compiler (defining the target OpenMP implementation)?

Are you sure the dependencies are actually correct in your code? It looks like there are loop carried dependencies and the parallel execution causes a race condition (impacting performance btw). OpenMP does not check that (this is impossible), this is your job.

Besides, why do you use tasks here? Basic for work-sharing directives seem fine at first glance unless you have a LOT of waves. If so then you will certainly create too many tasks serializing the execution anyway. I would understand the benefit with depend clauses but not here.

Last but not least: the memory access pattern on S seems really inefficient. The stride is huge so data locality is probably pretty low. I expect a lot of cache misses, slow DRAM fetches and a significant part of the (precious scarce) DRAM bandwidth to be wasted (possibly >90%)! I strongly advise you to fix this issue first because memory-bound code does not scale and it should make your sequential code significantly slower already. It might be possibly to change the layout to make S accesses more contiguous (at least more than currently).

Which compiler/openmp runtime do you use? Gcc is especially slow when it comes to tasking execution, due to a single task queue. In any case, your problem is likely too fine-grained for tasking execution. You have also a task barrier at the end of each task loop, which doesn't help for performance either.

Everything commented to your class mate in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79143272/openmp-taking-even-more-time-in-parallel also applies for you.

Instead of iterating over all rows in the inner loop, you should become clear about the concrete boundaries and reduce the iteration space. You will see that you don't create enough tasks for all threads in the first 10 thousands of waves and also in the last 10 thousands of waves. One/few thread will work on the iterations and the remaining threads are busy executing comparisons in the if statement.
